# How to update past values in to newly created field

Tags: workflow, field-update

I have created new field and updating the field with another field value using Workflow rule, When I create new record the field value is getting updated in the new field. Now the question is how do I update the past record values in the new field.

Do I have to do one time update or is there any way that I can populate using Workflow??

I am new to Sales cloud Customization and development. Please shed some light

Comment: easy way: export all data, update the new value based in the old value, upload again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a data clean up.

1. Export the data set of the records you want to update using dataloader. This will create a CSV file
2. Update the field values in Excel
3. Upload the revised dataset

Here is some docs on data loader: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_loader.htm&type=5

Here is a trailhead for dataloader https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/import-and-export-with-data-management-tools/use-data-loader-to-export-data

Answer (score 1):

You can use [priorValue](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5#PRIORVALUE) in workflow field update.

```
NewField__c = PriorValue(OldField__c)
```